# create model python in classic azure machine learning

Tags: python, azure

I read the documents in azure ML that they have supported a create model python pill but I go to the experiments and search for that pill but doesn't exist.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YMZ0.png)
Anyone can show me how can I create my own model in classic Azure ML. I want to implement SGDClassifier that only support in sklearn library
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/algorithm-module-reference/create-python-model)

Answer (score 0):

Machine Learning classic studio does not have a `Create python model` pill whereas you can get it using Machine learning.

[image]

[image]

Also, the Machine Learning Classic studio is about to get deprecated so I would recommend using the above Machine Learning resource which has an advanced and simple UX design that has many advantages.
[image]

You can find SGDClassifier in sklearn.linear_model

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
```

For more information on SGD Classifier you can refer [sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier — scikit-learn 0.24.2 documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) and [python-examples/SGDClassifier_example.py at master · WilliamQLiu/python-examples · GitHub](https://github.com/WilliamQLiu/python-examples/blob/master/sklearn/SGDClassifier_example.py)